COW filesystems (BTRFS, ZFS, bcachefs) scrubbing and RAID1 with mdadm on Linux
Suppose I create a two disks RAID1 volume with mdadm and then create a BTRFS/ZFS/bcachefs partition on it.
Than data on one of the two disks gets corrupted.
If I perform a scrub, there's no way for BTRFS/ZFS/bcachefs to correct the issue by copying the right data over the corrupted one.
As it would have if it was BTRFS/ZFS/bcachefs to manage the two physical disks by itself.
That's because mdadm hides the fact that there are two underlying physical disks.
Is that right?

Yes, when running on top of mdadm the ZFS, etc. scrub can not correct corruption that happend to the individual disks. That is one of the main reasons why those filesystems strongly prefer direct control over the disks without any unneccessary abstractions like raid controllers or software raid.
======That is all you need to know. Anything below are mostly irrelevant technical details======
An exception to this is when a drive self reports an error. The logic for traditional software raid usually looks something like this:

If both drives return the same, everything is fine
If a drive is missing the other one is used
If a drive reports an error ("I'm not sure about this data I'm about to give you") the other one is used
If both drives return data, neither returns an error and it's different there is no way to know what is correct. Usually the first piece of data is assumed to be correct, potentially not only returning incorrect data but also overwriting and corrupting the good data on the other drive.

If you are using ZFS, etc. the filesystem will still know something is wrong due to the checksums it keeps, but has no way to correct it because it sees only one block device total, that just returned bad data.
There is in theory a way to make it work with mdadm, by first formatting every disk with dm-integrity (this emulates per sector checksums on a block device level) and then using mdadm. Then if there is corruption, the virtual block device will return an error to mdadm, which can then do the appropreate things to not corrupt the overall raid. This is similar to the way enterprise grade hardware raid controllers used to work with compatible 520-byte sector HDDs. But at this point you'd probably use XFS on top of that since you can just assume the returned data to be either correct or unrecoverable.
But "faking" all of that at a block device level is slow and inefficient, which is the whole reason filesystems like ZFS were developed:
To integrate the RAID and most importantly per device checksumming functionality with the higher level logic to make the whole thing more efficient, for example by only having one journal, one set of checksums and minimizing the number of separate IO operations to read/write the data.

Thanks, that was a great answer. I particularly appreciated the details about dm-integrity and hardware RAID. It was something I always used to wonder about.
